# Dynamic rows don't appear

Tags: android, dynamic, rows

I have a class Store.java where I simply store 2 strings and an integer. Then I create an ArrayList object of the same. I do this so that I can populate the values from 2 spinners and an edit text into the ArrayList dynamically. I want to get these values displayed in a tabular format. Also I've created a subclass of Application so that the ArrayList can be easily updated and retrieved in other Activities. The problem is that when I click on the 'Bill' button  the dynamic rows are not added to the table layout.

Here is the relevant code:

(MyApp.java)

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

    ArrayList<store> B = null;

    public ArrayList<store> getState(){
        return B;
    }

    public void setState(ArrayList<store> B){
        this.B = B;
    }
}
```

(Bill.java)

```
public class Bill extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.setContentView(R.layout.calc);
        ArrayList<store> B = new ArrayList<store>();

        store temp1=null;

        MyApp appState = ((MyApp)getApplicationContext());
        appState.setState(B);
        B = appState.getState();
        TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.myTable);

        for(int i=0;i<B.size();i++)
        {  
            temp1=new store();
            TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
            tr.setId(100+i);
            temp1=B.get(i);      
            tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            TextView b = new TextView(this);
            b.setId(200+i);
            b.setText(temp1.getPizzaName()); 

            TextView b1 = new TextView(this);
            b1.setText(temp1.getPizzaSize());
            b1.setId(300+i);

            TextView b2 = new TextView(this);
            b2.setText(String.valueOf(temp1.getQuantity()));
            b2.setId(400+i);

            b.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tr.addView(b);

            b1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tr.addView(b1);


            b2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tr.addView(b2);

            tl.addView(tr,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to your code:

```
    ArrayList<store> B = new ArrayList<store>();

    store temp1=null;

    MyApp appState = ((MyApp)getApplicationContext());
    appState.setState(B);
    B = appState.getState();
```

You create a List, than set it as your state, then retrieve it again.
How do you want to has some data on it?

PS: Please follow the code conventions, you code is hard to read.

Your variable 'temp' is initialized once. You should make a new instance every time before add it to the List.

Comment: @Marcos Vasconcelos O no..I am so stupid...I wanted to 'set' the state in another activity and 'get' it here..in this one...I cant believe I cud do such a blunder...Thanx man...Thanx a lot..

Comment: @Marcos Vasconcelos : But I still have problem...All the rows are getting populated by the same value ie the last entered value...:-(

Comment: @Marcos Vasconcelos: I have posted the code..Please have a look.

Comment: Your variable temp is initialized once.  You should make a new instance every time before add it to the List.

Comment: @Marcos Vasconcelos: I am sorry I didnt get you. In which class should I make the changes? I am creating a new instance of temp for every new row in Bill.java.

Comment: You should do it in the edittext event. Before B.add(temp); you should use temp = new store();

Comment: @Marcos Vasconcelos: OMG...I was stuck with this for over two weeks...This is THE moment...I cant thank you enough man...(Hug)...Works perfectly fine....:-) Thanx a ton...Could I have your email id?

Comment: Well, i don't see a reason why not. "marcosavjr (at) hotmail.com"

Comment: Thanx again.. But I ll bug you more now..;-)